# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting

Tags: php

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting`

I get this error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '}' in /home/l2hantol/public_html/acp/core.php on line 37`

Line 37

```
function testServer($hostname,$user,$password,$database) {
    try {
        $handler = new PDO("mysql:host={$myip.zapto.org};dbname={$gameserver}",$root,$mypassword);
        $handler = null;
        return true;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Classes

class template {
    public $template;

    function load($filepath) {
        $this->template = preg_replace("#\{(.*)\}#","<?php echo $1; ?>",file_get_contents($filepath));
```

Comment: Whatever `{$myip.zapto.org}` is, it is wrong. Did you mean `{$myip}.zapto.org`? Also, `$gameserver` is undefined in this function.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial syntax error

Answer (score 1):

What is `$myip.zapto.org`? Probably you want something like this:

```
"mysql:host={$myip};dbname={$gameserver}"
```

Or if you need to build a more complex string, do it outside with something like this:

```
$host = $myip . "zapto.org"
$handler = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$gameserver}",$root,$mypassword);
```

**Edit:**

If `myip.zapto.org` is simply your domain name, you don't need `$` or `{}`, so you can simply write:

```
$handler = new PDO("mysql:host=myip.zapto.org;dbname={$gameserver}",$root,$mypassword);
```

Comment: myip.zapto.org
it's my ip but it's hidden behind no-ip's ip and because my ip is dynamic and it's always changing.

Comment: @JohnGrigoriadic, in that case, you do not need to put `$` in front of it or bracket around it. I've updated my answer with the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
function testServer($hostname,$user,$password,$database) {
    try {
    $handler = new PDO("mysql:host={$myip}.zapto.org;dbname={$gameserver}",$root,$mypassword);
    $handler = null;
    return true;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
}
}

// Classes

class template {
public $template;

function load($filepath) {
    $this->template = preg_replace("#\{(.*)\}#","<?php echo $1; ?>",
file_get_contents($filepath));
```

Comment: An explanation as to what you did? ;-)

Comment: From $handler = new PDO("mysql:host={$myip.zapto.org};dbname={$gameserver}",$root,$mypassword); to    $handler = new PDO("mysql:host={$myip}.zapto.org;dbname={$gameserver}",$root,$mypassword); -- I changed {$myip.zapto.org} to {$myip}.zapto.org

Comment: Why was this down-voted what is wrong with it?

Comment: Wasn't me, but have a look at the other answers given. It does make sense.

Comment: Thanks guys!
Laurent solution worked perfectly!

Comment: but now i have another problem it looks like it can't connect to my mysql and always says Error: Some of the details are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$handler = new PDO("mysql:host={$myip.zapto.org};dbname={$gameserver}"...
                                     -^       ^-
```

This part in your connection query is **not** considered as a string.

You probably want:

```
$handler = new PDO("mysql:host={$myip}.zapto.org;dbname={$gameserver}" ...
```

Although [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) looks like a cleaner solution:

```
$handler = new PDO(sprintf('mysql:host=%s.zapto.org;dbname=%s', $host, $dbname), 
$myip, $gameserver);
```